# Set a custom 'no results' message from invalid SPARQL queries

Tags: sparql, data-analysis, message, default, exploratory-data-analysis

Currently, I'm creating some SPARQL queries, which I am brand new at, for our data analysts. We want them to be able to fill in what they're looking for in custom search boxes that edit the query under the hood. So far I have most working, but I was hoping there is a way to return a custom message if they, say, search for a non-existing table in our dataset. Currently, they get the default "query returned to results" message, but I'd like to change that to something more informative.

I've tried a few loose ideas, but as a newbie myself, it's hard for me to figure out how to implement anything. For instance, I've tried using filters and such to see if I can change a value if the results return a count of 0, but that is not a valid query, unfortunately. I've tried putting the filters in OPTIONAL blocks, creating some BINDs, trying to work with IF statements, etc., but can't seem to get them all working how I'd like.

Does anyone have any experience implementing something like this, or is this idea even possible?? Thanks in advance for any input/tips

Comment: I'm wondering how you would be able to know why a query returns no results? I mean, SPARQL can became arbitrarily complex, how do you get  insights of which evaluation of whch triple pattern is empty such that a join becomes empty? Or that a basic graph patterns is empty becomes of something? Or am I misunderstanding your goal? Computing a count for each triple pattern and each join would be horribly inefficient if even possible via a single SPARQL query. Anything beyond would be touching statistics about the dataset, e.g. whch classes or properties exist, histograms etc

Comment: if my assumption of your goal is wrong, maybe you can give an example via a SPARQL query and also one of the SPARQL queries you already tried to workaround?

Comment: So for example, I currently have it set up so that users can search for a table name, and that table name is passed as a parameter to a FILTER argument in the SPARQL query. If someone puts in a name incorrectly so that FILTER returns no results, there is the message "No data found" output. What I'm trying to do is, instead of that "No data found" message, change it to something else. So far, none of my workarounds have worked. I've thought of trying something like binding a string value to output on queries that return a result set of 0, but can't get that to work, either